# Passing values between two separate jsf pages

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I need help! I have spent a few days on and off searching for solution to the following use cases. Pardon me for the absence of code.

One Web Input/Edit forms:

User Details – contains user names, uploadfileName etc., and 'Save'
    and 'Upload'  buttons

1. User fills in his details
2. User clicks 'Upload'
3. System opens the Primefaces FileUpload screen
4. User upload picture
5. System closes the  Primefaces FileUpload customized screen
6. System updates the uploadfileName outputText with the  uploaded
   fileName.
7. User clicks to save user details.
8. System validates and saves user details.

Primefaces FileUpload customized screen: This is embedded in a Dialog and is in a separate xhtml file (for reusability).

The issue is how to pass the uploadedfileName value from the Upload Dialog to update the uploadfileName outputText in the calling (master) User page.

For example, in Vaadin, one might use ActionListener or ReturnActionListener in the case of Trinidad.

Thanks for your help(in advance).

Answer (score 0):

Put the bean in the view scope. The one and same bean instance is then available across all forms in the same view.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Register {
    // ...
}
```

You can inject view scoped beans in each other. You could inject the bean of the upload form in the bean of the registration form and access it in the action method.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Register {

    @ManagedProperty("#{upload}")
    private Upload upload;

    // ...
}
```

It doesn't matter if it are physically separate pages, as long as you include them in one and same master view by e.g. `<ui:include>` or a composite, then the same view state is maintained across postbacks.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, for you quick response. I shall come back and thank you some more if your solution works. I have already wasted so much time on the problem, I need a break from it. BTW Does that mean that my popup dialog.xhtml that contains the Primefaces FileUpload can't contain f:view?

Comment: Why should it ever? It's ultimately just part of the same HTML page and should absolutely not contain `<html><head><body>`. Note that I assume that you're using `<p:dialog>`.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Instead of setting both beans as `@ViewScoped`, is it possible to set the `UploadBean` as `@RequestScoped` and inject the `RegisterBean` into it? After that, we can call some `set` method of the `RegisterBean` to update the uploaded item's name?

Comment: @Mr.J4mes: that'll work for `mode="simple"` which uploads by non-ajax submit, but that won't work if the upload takes place by ajax which happens effectively in a different request than the submit.